# how to extract a column from mysql result set?

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

What would be the best way to extract a column out of mysql results set? My result set is like:

```
[0] = ('id'=>1, 'name'=>a),
[1] = ('id'=>2, 'name'=>b),
[2] = ('id'=>3, 'name'=>c)
```

How can I extract 'name' column as an array from this? I can do it using for loop. But wondering if there are any better reusable solution?

Comment: Do you need the id column? Why not just tell the query to fetch only the name column?

Comment: @karim79: this is simplified dummy result set.

Comment: @understack - got you, sorry for the dud comment.

Comment: @understack but that doesn't answer @karim's question. Why fetch more columns than needed? If you only want to process name, then just fetch name only. Also, why would you need to extract the name column at all? Why can't you just use the entire resultset?

Comment: @Gordon: All I want is a column as an array from an already prefetched result set. I'm not sure why it's causing confusion as it's clearly mentioned in the question itself.

Comment: @understack mainly because it appears like you want to do something unnecessary. Just trying to understand the UseCase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to do this.

```
function getName($elem) {
  return $elem['name'];
}
$names = array_map('getName', $input);

// PHP 5.3.0 or higher allows anonymous functions
$names = array_map(function($e) { return $e['name']; }, $input);
```

Comment: +1, this *or* `array_walk` would be the way to go, `array_map` is however, slightly easier to use.

Comment: `array_map` won't destroy the original array either... Walk will... http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php is the documentation page for `array_walk`

Answer (score 1):

```
$rows = array(
 array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'a'), 
 array('id'=>2, 'name'=>'b'),
 array('id'=>3, 'name'=>'c')
);


$names = array();    
foreach ($rows as $row) {
 $names[] = $row['name'];
}
```

Using a simple loop will execute much faster than using something like array_map (which incurs much more overhead). Difference in speed can be as much as 100%.